# countdownt to go website on codeigniter

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to make my first countdown for the web , how to create a script of the countdown after the time runs straight into my web ?? in codeIgniter

this my script

```
var target_date = new Date('Sep, 19, 2015,21:26:00').getTime();
var days, hours, minutes, seconds;
var countdown = document.getElementById('countdown');
setInterval(function () {
    var current_date = new Date().getTime();
    var seconds_left = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;
    days = parseInt(seconds_left / 86400);
    seconds_left = seconds_left % 86400;

    hours = parseInt(seconds_left / 3600);
    seconds_left = seconds_left % 3600;

    minutes = parseInt(seconds_left / 60);
    seconds = parseInt(seconds_left % 60);

    countdown.innerHTML = '<div id="days" class="timer_box"><h1>' + days +  '</h1> <p>Days</p></div> <div id="days" class="timer_box"><h1>' + hours + '</h1> <p>Hours</p></div> <div id="days" class="timer_box"><h1>'
    + minutes + '</h1> <p>Minutes</p></div> <div id="days" class="timer_box"><h1>' + seconds + '</h1> <p>Seconds</p></div>';  

}, 1000);
```

Comment: what is the specific problem ? Codeigniter is completely irrelevant as it is a php framework that runs on server and javascript runs in browser

Comment: your question is unclear